# Short story about a guy who turns an untranslatable alien signal into a sports betting wire

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, communication

I was re-reading Varley's [*A Persistence of Vision*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?32052) and the [Eight Worlds](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?567) story "[The Black Hole Passes](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50782)" which uses the "Ophiuchi Hotline" setting reminded me of this story.  I read this many years ago (1990s? 1980s?); I believe it was before the turn of the millennium, but I can't be more specific.

[SETI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_for_extraterrestrial_intelligence) is successful!  Earth discovers a signal being beamed into space from unknown aliens many lightyears away.  (Too far away for conversation to be practical.)
Unfortunately, the signal can't be decoded; symbols are assigned to repeated patterns, but scientists can't determine what any of it means.  There are no obvious mathematical patterns, or any of the other tropes commonly used to decode alien messages.

The protagonist, who may have a math/science background, is a sports [handicapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicapping#Outcome_prediction).  He sees, or someone shows him, the signal.  The data reminds him of sports [box scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_score), and he decides that certain patterns of symbols are "teams" and others represent "scores."  He convinces some (possibly less-than-legal) organization to start taking bets on "games" and becomes successful handicapping them.

(My memory is very hazy, but I seem to recall he sent out a daily/weekly info sheet to subscribers along the lines of "XKMESNT 5:2 to beat EIWNQR at IWERNR" where all the sport and team and place names looked like keyboard mashing.)

Comment: Looks like its in a 1988 issue of Analog, judging from this clip https://www.google.com/search?q=%22betting+wire%22+%22analog+science+fiction%22&sca_esv=578293274&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=JYRBZbuBEPLbkPIPkoCNyA0&ved=0ahUKEwj7p4aVr6GCAxXyLUQIHRJAA9kQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22betting+wire%22+%22analog+science+fiction%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIiciYmV0dGluZyB3aXJlIiAiYW5hbG9nIHNjaWVuY2UgZmljdGlvbiJInhxQhQRYmRtwA3gAkAEAmAGfAqAB-BiqAQYwLjE2LjK4AQPIAQD4AQGIBgE&sclient=gws-wiz-books

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is ["Wait Till Next Year"](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56997) by Robin Rowland, from the November 1988 issue of Analog.  Searching Google book search for "Wait Till Next Year" and "betting wire" finds this excerpt:

> "OK," Benny said as he swigged a can of beer, "we tell this lunkhead
> (he meant the AI) to take my software and then assume that DRS 2 is a
> bets wire..."

and

> "R-T-E-B-S-F to show at the next time he, she or it races at
> Querl-ugh-vee-ee-eye-four."

which both sound like they are from the right story.

This [link](https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/SF/AN/AN_1988_11.pdf) has the full story, which provides the clincher quote (thanks @user14111), starting on page 92.

> The box score from the Yoeertsha shows that Casgthwyusnbhksow has great potential. He had a 543 RFC and a 219 Azy with an average ura per game of 174. I hope for the day when we will all see Casgthwyusnbhksow romp across those far off playing fields. In the meantime, as they're saying (or were saying seven hundred years ago) on DaRass, the same as they're saying here in Toronto, "Wait till next year."
>
> I just wish I knew what the hell they're playing up there.

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll try to dig it up.  Doesn't Luminist have the 1980s now?

Comment: Thanks for the edits @user14111 - you beat me to it!

Comment: @user14111 Excellent, thanks for the assist!